# How do I set up a :through ActiveRecord association in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having trouble figuring out associations. I need to link up a User to Feedback through Transactions. Feedback has transaction_id property and Transaction has seller_id. How would I do that using associations? Here is what I have so far, appreciate your help! Thanks!

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feedbacks
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
end
```

Comment: Transaction is a dangerous name, as "transaction" is method inside of active record. Sooner or later you get a name clash, so better rename it now.

Comment: Agreed, I am actually using PlatformTransaction for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User -> Transactions -> Feedback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions
    has_many :feedbacks, through: :transactions, foreign_key: 'seller_id'
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feedback
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'seller_id'
end

class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :transaction
end
```

Comment: Sorry, ran thought the association quick then realized I needed to keep your foreign key declaration. Edit to reflect that.

Comment: You also need to let `User` know how to look up `Transaction`s using the primary and foreign key definitions otherwise `@user.transactions` will look for a `user_id` column that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks wasn't sure about that. Is that the correct form?

Comment: Changed it to also use the newer hash syntax across the board.

Comment: Does not work:

feedback = Feedback.includes(:seller).where(["user_id = ?", user_id]).order(updated_at: :desc)

ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (Association named 'seller' was not found on Feedback; perhaps you misspelled it?):

Comment: To make `Feedback.seller` work you need to add `belongs_to :seller, through: :transaction` to the `Feedback` class.

Comment: though: is not a valid belongs_to key

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not. I am still debugging though. Will update, thanks for the help!

Comment: Are any of the associations working? It's a pretty simple problem that I've used an many apps.

Comment: Don't forget to reload your environment or restart your web server as I believe Rails has to reload the models to pick up the associations.

Comment: also adding examples of what isn't working and the web server console messages will help us troubleshoot.

Comment: App 29627 stdout: ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError (Association named 'seller' was not found on Feedback; perhaps you misspelled it?):
App 29627 stdout:   app/controllers/api_controller.rb:881:in `get_feedback'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100426/discussion-between-nebulus-and-beartech).